Is this correct notation for set of equivalence class and quotient sets for directed limit of directed system of groups.
Background:
The following is taken from: A Graduate Course In Algebra - Volume 1
by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz, and How to Prove it by: Dan Velleman.
Definition 1: Let $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of groups.  Then, the Cartesian product
$$\prod_{i\in I}G_i=\{f:I\to \cup_{i\in I}G_i:i\mapsto f(i)\in G_i\}$$
becomes a group under the following pointwise operation
$$f\cdot g \text{ such that }(f\cdot g)(i)=f(i)\cdot g(i)\in G_i$$
with unit element $1$ defined by $1(i)=1_{G_i}$ for each $i\in I$.
Definition 2: The direct sum of the family of the subgroup is defined as
$$\oplus_{i\in I}G_i=\{f\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i \text{ such that } f(i)\neq 1_{G_i},\text{ for all but finite number of }i\}$$
with the restricted operation.
Definition 3:  Suppose $R$ is an equivalence-relation on a set $A,$ and $x\in A.$  Then the *equivlanece class of x with respect to * $R$ is the set
$$[x]_R=\{y\in A\mid yRx\}\quad\quad (*)$$
If $R$ is clear from context, then we just write $[x]$ instead of $[x]_R.$  The set of all equivalence classes of elements of $A$ is called $A$ modulo $R,$ and is denoted $A/R$.
$$A/R=\{[x]_R\mid x\in A\}=\{X\subset A\mid \exists x\in A(X=[x]_R)\}\quad\quad (**)$$
Definition 4:  Let $(I, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set with the property that for any two elements $i,j$ there is some $k\in I$ such that $i\preceq k, j\preceq k$.
Definition 5:  A directed system of sets (groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.) indexed by $I$ is a collection of sets (rrespectively groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.)  $X_i, i\in I)$, and maps (respectively homomorphisms, contiuous maps, etc.)  $f_{ij}:X_i\to X_j$, defined whenever $i\preceq j$, satisfies the following compatibility conditions:

$f_{ik}=f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}, i\preceq j \preceq k$, and
$f_{ii}=\mathrm{Id}_{X_i}$.

Definition 6:  A direct (or inductive) limit of the directed system of groups $G_i$, is defined by giving a group $G$ and a homomorphism
$$\phi_iG_i\to G$$
for any $i\in I$ such that

if $i<j$ then $\phi_i=\phi_j\circ \phi_{ij}$,
if $(G',\phi'_i)$ is another group and family of homormophisms with the same property then there exists a unique homomorphism
$$\phi: G\to G'$$
such that $\phi_i=\phi\circ \phi'_i$ for any $i\in I$.

The direct limit can be constructed as the quotient of the subgroup $\oplus_i G_i$ of $\prod_i G_i$ as follows:  $$\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i=\oplus_i G_i/\sim$$
where, $x_i\in G_i$ is equivalent to $x_j\in G_j$ if and only if
$$\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\phi_{jk}(x_j)$$
for some $k\in I,$ with the additional structure that the product of $x_i\in G_i, x_j\in G_j$ is defined as the product of their iimages in $G_k$.
Questions:
In continuation of the post. In that previous post, I ask if the equivalence relation $\sim$ in mathematical notation is translated as:
$x_i\sim x_j$ if and only if $G_i\xrightarrow{\phi_{ik}(x_i)}G_k=G_j\xrightarrow{\phi_{jk}(x_j)}G_k$.  Here I would like to know if the notation for the set of equivalence class and the quotient set according to Definition 3 is as follows:
Letting $A=\oplus_{i\in I}G_i, R=\sim, x=x_i$ and $y=x_j,$ then the set of equivalence class in Definition 3 $(*)$ of $$\varinjlim_{i\in I} G_i=\oplus_i G_i/\sim$$ is denoted as:
$$[x_{i\in I}]_\sim=\{x_{j\in I}\in \oplus_{i\in I} G_i\mid x_{j\in I}\sim x_{i\in I}\}$$
and its quotient set, translating from Definition 3 $(**)$ is:
$$\oplus_{i\in I} G_i/\sim=\{[x_{i\in I}]_\sim\mid x_{i\in I}\in \oplus_{i\in I} G_i\}=\{G_i\subset \oplus_{i\in I} G_i\mid \exists x_{i\in I}\in \oplus_{i\in I} G_i(G_i=[x_{i\in I}]_\sim\}$$
Can someone tell me if my notations are correct please?
Thank you in advance

This "direct sum" ... are your groups Abelian? We would in the category of all groups consider the free product, which is not what you've described as far as I can tell.

@FShrike I just copied the definitions verbatium from the cited text.  The reason I am asking about this is because when I see algebra textbooks talking about constructing direct limits from directed systems of algebraic structure, and then they use quotient sets by forming equivalence relations, they don't specific what would be a good notation for the set of equivalence classes and quotient sets using set builder notations.

It is extremely important to answer the question of whether or not the colimit is being considered in the category of Abelian groups, or in the category of all groups

@FShrike I think we can safely assume that it is.  The concept of Free Groups get introduced later.  Also, direct and inverse limits are introduced within the section on exact sequences which comes right after product of groups.  So it is safe to assume that it is for abelian groups.

$$\bigoplus_{i\in I}G_i/\sim=\{[x_{i\in I}]_\sim|x_{i\in I}\in\bigoplus_{i\in I}G_i\}$$Is correct. But: $$=\{G_i\subseteq\bigoplus_{i\in I}G_i|\exists x_{i\in I}\in\bigoplus_{i\in I}G_i(G_i=[x_{i\in I}]_\sim)\}$$Is not correct / not meaningful for the simple reason that $G_i$ is being overloaded. What is the set $\{A\subseteq A\}$? I think you're getting at, equivalence classes are really sets so we're looking at subsets of $\bigoplus_{i\in I}G_i$ but you absolutely shouldn't call those subsets $G_i$ as well. Now $G$ carries two meanings! Just stick with the first notation.
As commented under other recent questions of yours, $x_i\sim x_j$ iff $G_i\overset{\phi_{ik}(x_i)}{\longrightarrow}G_k=G_j\overset{\phi_{jk}(x_j)}{\longrightarrow}G_k$ doesn't make any sense / is wrong.  First of all, if $G_i\neq G_j$ then the two "functions" have different domains so could not be equal. Secondly these "functions" are not even functions. $\phi_{ik}$ is, sure. But $x_i$ is just an element of $G_i$! $\phi_{ik}(x_i)$ is just an element of $G_k$! It is not a function $G_i\to G_k$. I appreciate that you want to use the definition of the set-theoretic product $\prod_i G_i$ as the set of all choice functions $I\to\bigcup_i G_i$ but if you insist on that perspective, $x:I\to\bigcup_i G_i$ would be the element of the product, the function; each evaluation $x_i:=x(i)$ would not be a function really, it would just be an element of $G_i$.
If you have an inductive system of Abelian groups, $\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i$ is the quotient group of $\bigoplus_{i\in I}G_i$ by the subgroup generated by all elements of the form $x_i-x_j$ where $x_i,x_j\in G_i,G_j$ and there exists $k,i,j\preceq k$, with $\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\phi_{jk}(x_j)$. Taking a quotient by a subgroup immediately tells you you have a sensible group structure at the end of the day. More concretely, it is a theorem that the general elements $\sum_{i\in I}x_i$ and $\sum_{j\in I}y_j$ of the direct sum - where all but finitely many $x_i,y_i$ are zero - are related by $\sim$ iff. there exists a $k$ larger than all $i$ in the support of $y_i,x_i$ with $\sum_i\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\sum_i\phi_{ik}(y_i)$ in $G_k$. This observation is important in proving filtered colimits are exact.
Colimits along a general diagram of set-sized shape (not necessarily a poset) still exist for (Abelian) groups but the relation is harder to describe. The subgroup definition I gave is probably the cleanest in that case.
(yes you can define elements as functions $\{\ast\}\to X$ but that would be missing my point and just confusing).
For my claim about "it is a theorem"; let $Z\subseteq\bigoplus_i G_i$ be the subgroup generated by all elements of form $x_i-x_j$ where $\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\phi_{jk}(x_j)$ for some $k$ greater than $i,j$. Let $Z'$ be the set of all elements $\sum_{i\in F}x_i$, $F\subseteq I$ finite, for which there is a $k$ greater than every element of $F$ such that $\sum_{i\in F}\phi_{ik}(x_i)=0$. We want to show $Z'=Z$. Firstly $Z'$ contains every element of type $x_i-x_j$ as is obvious; the "$k$" is the same. Secondly, $Z'$ is easily a subgroup; if $k$ works for $\sum_{i\in F}x_i$ and $k'$ works for $\sum_{i\in F'}x_i$, there is a further $\kappa$ greater than both $k$ and $k'$ (as the poset is directed) and then $\sum_{i\in F\cup F'}\phi_{i\kappa}(x_i)=\phi_{k\kappa}\left(\sum_{i\in F}\phi_{ik}(x_i)\right)+\phi_{k'\kappa}\left(\sum_{i\in F'}\phi_{ik'}(x_i)\right)=0+0=0$ as desired. Therefore $Z'$ contains $Z$, as it is a subgroup containing all the generators of $Z$.
For $Z$ contains $Z'$; note that each $x_i$ is equivalent mod $Z$ to $\phi_{ik}(x_i)$, if the $x_i$ and $k$ are as in the definition of $Z'$, and then $\sum_{i\in F}\phi_{ik}(x_i)=0$ is of course in $Z$ as $Z$ contains zero. So $Z=Z'$.
The way to think about this; it tells you two elements are equivalent if they are eventually the same once you map them to some $G_k$, $k$ large.

You can also describe the subgroup you mod out by as the subgroup generated by all elements of the form $x_i - \phi_{ik}(x_i)$ for all $i\preceq k$.

@FShrike when you say "it is a theorem that the general elements $\sum_{i\in I}x_i$ and $\sum_{j\in I}y_j$ of the direct sum - where all but finitely many $x_i,y_i$ are zero - are related by $\sim$ iff. there exists a $k$ larger than all $i$ in the support of $y_i,x_i$ with $\sum_i\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\sum_i\phi_{ik}(y_i)$ in $G_k$", is there a book reference that this theorem appears in?  Also, can I ask you about this related post....

@FShrike it has to do with how to describe a function $f$ being compatible with an equivalence relation $R$.  The thing is, for the case of direct limits build from a directed systems of groups, there are a lot of composition maps going on and I am having a hard time choosing the correct subsitutions for the defintion quoted in that post.  :(

@ArturoMagidin it is really weird to see elements of groups be operated on using addition and subtraction.  If we have something like $x_i-\phi_{ik}(x_i)$, isn't that equivalent to $x_i\cdot{\phi_{ik}(x_i)}^{-1}$ for multiplicative notation?

@Seth If you use Abelian groups which I think is implicit in this question, additive notation is the way to go. Seriously good to get used to it

@FShrike additive notations for groups are just weird, when all I see about quotient groups has been with multiplicative notations. Unless they have to do with modules.  Also where did  you learn that theorem from about the sum of elements of a group and equivalence relations?

@Seth Additive notation is nice and reminds you that the operation is commutative. Almost all homological algebra is done with additive notation; it's standard for Abelian groups, very standard. But yes $x_i-x_j$ is analogous to $x_ix_j^{-1}$. The "it is a theorem" is used in Weibel's book on homological algebra but it's not a complicated proof. I'll sketch it.

@FShrike hey can I ask you a quick question here about notation.  I just want to know if my understanding of what compatible function is for directed limit of groups matches what is usually stated for equivalence relations.  Thank you in advance.
